# Update Facebook SDK with Ionic Capacitor (capacitor-firebase-auth)

Tags: ios, facebook, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, capacitor

So I'm having trouble updating the Facebook SDK for iOS and Android on my Ionic Capacitor 3 project. The Facebook SDK for iOS has to be version 8 or higher to support the new iOS 14 tracking updates.

The thing is, the Facebook dashboard sends me to this url [Facebook upgrade guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/upgrade-guide/). For iOS, you only have to add some pods to your Podfile, but this doesn't seem to change anything. I'm using the capacitor plugin capacitor-firebase-auth to handle the authentication.

I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong, is it a problem that I don't use the Facebook SDK directly, by using it through capacitor-firebase-auth?

This is the warning I'm getting:
[image]

I'm using:

- Ionic 5
- Capacitor 3
- capacitor-firebase-auth 3.0.0
- My Podfile.lock shows a FacebookSDK of 5.15.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by using the [Facebook Capacitor Login](https://github.com/capacitor-community/facebook-login) plugin. Keep in mind that it took 3 days before the iOS SDK version in the Facebook Dashboard got updated!